# Looking for formula for variation of binomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-theorem

Is there variation of the binomial theorem as follows?

$$\sum_{i=0}^n {m \choose i} a^{m-i} b^i $$

I am trying to find a formula for it that is a function of $n$ without summation notation. I think you would call this is a solution in closed form. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^n {\color{red}{n} \choose i} a^{n-i} b^i=(a+b)^n$

Comment: that is the binomial theorem, which is not what i'm looking for

Comment: You want a factorization for that polynomial in $a$ and $b$?

Comment: yes, if one exists. is this possible?

Comment: This seems to be related, it studies when $b=1$. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409523

Comment: also related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139299/how-to-evaluate-a-truncated-binomial-series-in-the-infinity-limit

Comment: If $n\geq m$ it is $(a+b)^m$.  For $n < m$, this is a partial sum of binomial coefficients, there is no simple formula.  For $a+b = 1$ you could estimate it using the central limit theorem.

Comment: per site guidelines, please share with us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you were hoping for but we certainly can write your sum as a function of $n$ without summation notation using [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2.E4) expression for truncated hypergeometric series. We have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{m}{i}a^{m-i}b^i=a^m(-b/a)^n\frac{(-m)_n}{n!}{_2F}_1\left({-n,1 \atop 1-n+m};-\frac{a}{b}\right),
$$
where $(x)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol. Using transformations for the hypergeometric function may be able to put this in a more compact form.